# Draw frame around achartengine chart

Tags: android, achartengine

I'd like to "box" a time chart by extending lines from the ends of the X and Y axes like this:

```
   ----------------------
   |                    |
10 +                    |
   |                    |
 5 +                    |
   |                    |
   ---+---+---+---+---+--
      1   2   3   4   5
```

I have the same color for the margins and the chart background.

Just to clarify: I don't want secondary axes. And I do not want grids.

I haven't found a readily available API for this, but I guess it could be done when drawing the background or making the grid fit the entire chart.  What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I guess this isn't a feature many people need. I went on and implemented a solution which I'm not proud of, but which Works For Me™. I ended up with subclassing the TimeChart class and overriding draw():

```
    @Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, int x, int y, int width, int height,
        Paint paint) {
    super.draw(canvas, x, y, width, height, paint);
    int[] margins = mRenderer.getMargins();
    int left = x + margins[1];
    int top = y + margins[0];
    int right = x + width - margins[3];
    int legendSize = getLegendSize(mRenderer, height / 5, mRenderer.getAxisTitleTextSize());
    int bottom = y + height - margins[2] - legendSize;
    paint.setColor(mRenderer.getAxesColor());
    canvas.drawLine(left, top, right, top, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(right, top, right, bottom, paint);
}
```